# How to use &block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block, yield

I'm trying to use blocks in Ruby, I have this code:

```
  def positions
    return horizontally_position if orientation == "horizontally"
    vertically_position
  end

  def horizontally_position
    res = []
    for x in position[0]..end_coord(0) 
      res << [x, position[1]]
    end
    return res
  end

  def vertically_position
    res = []
    for y in position[1]..end_coord(1)
      res << [position[0], y]
    end
    return res
  end
```

There seems to be repeated code , and want to use a block or to a yield improve performance , but do not know how!

Do this :

```
  def positions
    return h_v_position(0, {[x, position[1]]}) if orientation == "horizontally"
    h_v_position(1, {[position[0], y]})
  end

  def h_v_positions(coord, &block) 
    res = []
    for x in position[coord]..end_coord(coord) 
      res << block.call
    end
    return res
  end
```

But isn't work.. there is any help?

Comment: If i'm interpreting this right, I think instead of passing a block, you just want to pass the array `[x, position[1]]` or `[position[0], y]`. Also, when using a block in Ruby, you pass the argument like you did, but inside the method, you would call the block with `block.call`. But, blocks are blocks. They are those `{ stuff in here }` that you would use to pass specific arguments to methods for use. But, in your case, it looks like you're passing information in an array to store in another array called `res` and returning that.

Comment: Thanks for that , I found the solution to my problem, I will post it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After think and searched in google I found the best way to do this, and understood how to use `&blocks` and `yields` in Ruby.

In the bigining, my problem was this repeted code:

```
  def horizontally_position
    res = []
    for x in position[0]..end_coord(0) 
      res << [x, position[1]]
    end
    return res
  end

  def vertically_position
    res = []
    for y in position[1]..end_coord(1)
      res << [position[0], y]
    end
    return res
  end
```

> The first thing I do to aboid the repeated code was use a `yield`:

```
  def position_by(coord) # ²
    res = []
    for n in position[coord]..end_coord(coord) 
      res <<  yield(n) # ³
    end
    return res
  end  

  def horizontally_position # ¹
    position_by(0) { |n| [n, position[1]] } # ⁴
  end

  def vertically_position # ¹
    position_by(1) { |n| [position[0], n] } # ⁴
  end
```

¹ When this method will called, it will call to `position_by(1)` or `position_by(0)`.
² This method will start to execute and when it comes to `<< yield(n)`...
³ It will come again to `vertically_position`" or `horizontally_position` and will replace the `yield` in `position_by` for the code in brackets in `horizontally_position` (or `vertically_position`). Sorry for the redundancy.

After do that I saw the method `position_by(coord)` and wish to refactor it a little.

> First refactor, using `yield`:

```
  def position_by(end_coor)
    position[end_coor]..end_coord(end_coor).map do |x|    
        yield x
    end
  end
```

> Then use a `&block`:

```
  def position_by(coord, &block) # ⁵
        (position[coord]..end_coord(coord)).map &block
  end
```

⁵ Here we are mapping each position to a `& block` , and a block can be [ x , position ( 1) ] or [position ( 0 ) , y] , Where x or and will be replace for the position [ coord ] corresponding.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to handle block arguments you can either use implicit yield:

```
def foo
  yield
end
```

or you can pass the block explicitly and call it with `block.call`:

```
def foo(&block)
  block.call
end
```

So if you replace `res << &block` with `res << block.call` the block should be called properly.